# Alternate ways to open Google Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I have been trying to open Google Cloud Shell Editor and it refuses to open. It was working fine a few minutes ago and it opens on my other account as well.

I have been trying to open Google Cloud Shell Editor and it refuses to open. It was working fine a few minutes ago and it opens on my other account as well. I tried doing the following

1. Allowing all third party cookies
2. Cleared all cookies
3. Resetting the default settings for google account

I can't get it to work. Please give me your suggestions.